# History/partial search with up-arrow on scala shell

Tags: linux, scala, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings, interactive-shell

How can I make the scala interactive shell program behave [this way](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59846/bash-history-search-partial-up-arrow) (using the up-arrow to go to the last command if I haven't typed anything or go to the last command given in the shell beginning with what I typed) instead of the reverse-i-search?

Comment: Your linked answer works. JLine uses .inputrc.

Comment: I have those commands on .inputrc and it doesn't result in the desirable behavior for me (it works for bash though).

Comment: WFM on 2.11.8, 2.12.0. They upgraded their JLine at some point, which might matter. Anyway thanks for the feature tip. It beats `:h? text`, `:line 2469`, up-arrow, by a lot.

Comment: You're right I installed 2.12.0 and it works now (I was using 2.11.6 that comes when I install scala via apt), you can answer the question I'll accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Scala REPL uses JLine for readline functionality, and current versions support these `.inputrc` mappings:

```
## arrow up
"\e[A":history-search-backward
## arrow down
"\e[B":history-search-forward
```

and they work as you describe, enter a line prefix then up-arrow.

Probably the clunky `:h?` command can be retired. Or I guess that finds text anywhere on a line. `:history` line numbers are still useful for `:edit 2463+10`.